# how to fix Flutter and Dart version, null-safety in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, dart

The difference of the Android Studio version always gives me the problem of not being able to export the app's file.apk.

For example: I am now facing the same problem with an application developed using Flutter, but this time I could not solve the problem and I am looking for someone to help me.

**Problem:** My version differs from the version in which the application was developed. By the way, I downloaded the Flutter version that was used, but it does not fix the problem.
**Note:** I do not have experience in application development but I want to get rid of this problem in a systematic way.

[screen shot with error message rendered somewhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2ZzA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading the flutter sdk by typing this command in terminal

```
flutter upgrade
```

same for the dependencies

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

Answer (score -1):

increase your flutter version for example
your current version is 2.7.0 change it to 2.8.0

if you need more help you can contact me on whatsapp +919682561431